# How to not display duplicate values mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Thus, the script displays the values, but duplicates them, many values ​​with the same email and date. You need to get unique values, for example, there may be the same emails, but with a different date. But not the same emails with the same date.
DISTINCT after SELECT does not work, as well as applying it before each field.
group by and order by too, they cannot add more than two fields. When I accept group by email, it displays all the unique values, but does not display the values ​​that are also needed when two identical emails, but different dates, it displays stupidly one email and that's it.
What to do help.

```
SELECT concat(last_name, ' ', first_name, ' ', middle_name) as 'ФИО',
    email,
    phone,
    created_at,
    total,
    color
  FROM user
INNER JOIN `user` ON `order`.user_id = `user`.id
INNER JOIN `color` ON `user`.color_id = `color`.id
```

Comment: Please add sample data and expected output as text.

Comment: Apply distinct to email `DISTINCT(email)` and then group the results like so `GROUP BY email`.

Comment: DISTINCT only for email displays other fields incorrectly that do not match email

Comment: Sure, I looked again into your query and saw that DISTINCT will not be enough to guarantee uniqueness. Sorry about that. So go get uniqueness, you need to order, group the results using either primary keys from the three tables. Note, for the order and grouping to work as expected, the fields you're grouping with should be included in the select clause.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the keyword DISTINCT after the SELECT. 
Example:

```
SELECT DISTINCT concat(last_name, ' ', first_name, ' ', middle_name) as 'ФИО',
    email,
    phone,
    created_at,
    total,
    color
  FROM user
```

Comment: I wrote that DISTINCT does not help
DISTINCT after SELECT does not work, as well as applying it before each field. group by and order by too,

Answer (score 0):

You have order the results by combing fields from the three tables:

```
SELECT concat(last_name, ' ', first_name, ' ', middle_name) as 'ФИО',
    email,
    phone,
    created_at,
    total,
    color,
    o.PRIMARY_KEY_HERE,
    c.id 
  FROM user AS u 
INNER JOIN `order` AS o ON o.user_id = u.id
INNER JOIN `color` AS c ON c.id = u.color_id 
ORDER BY u.email, o.PRIMARY_KEY_HERE, c.id
```

**Note**
The query has been refactored to satisfy the ORDER BY clause.